# Acces @ViewChild NgForm refence from child components in parent component

Tags: angular, angular-forms, viewchild, viewchildren

I have following app structure:

```
+--------------------------------------------+                                                                         
|                 Parent                     |                                                                         
|+------------------------------------------+|                                                                         
||                Header                    ||                                                                         
||  <form #headerForm="ngForm">             ||                                                                         
||       ...                                ||                                                                         
||  </form>                                 ||                                                                         
|+------------------------------------------+|                                                                         
|+------------------------------------------+|                                                                         
||                Content                   ||                                                                         
||  <form #contentForm="ngForm">            ||                                                                         
||      ...                                 ||                                                                         
||                                          ||                                                                         
||  </form>                                 ||                                                                         
||                                          ||                                                                         
|+------------------------------------------+|                                                                         
+--------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to reset the states of the forms in the header and content **from** the *Parent* component. I tried to use *@ViewChild/@ViewChildren* from the parent component, but I do not know how to access the childs form refs.

So far I was forced to get a reference of the *Header* and *Content* components in the *Parent* and call a *resetForm*  method:

```js
export class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChildren('componentWithForm') componentsWithForms: QueryList<unknown>;

  ...

  this.componentsWithForms.forEach(component => (component as any).resetFormState());




@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
   ...
  providers: [{ provide: 'componentWithForm', useExisting: forwardRef(() => HeaderComponent) }],
})
export class HeaderComponent {

  @ViewChild('headerForm') headerForm: NgForm;

  ...

  resetFormState() {
     this.headerForm.reset();
   }
```

Although this technically helps it leads to some ugly TypeScript casting - which I could work around creating a base-class *ComponentWithForm*, inheriting the Header/Content from it and setting the provider like

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
   ...
  providers: [{ provide: ComponentWithForm, useExisting: forwardRef(() => HeaderComponent) }],
})
export class HeaderComponent extends ComponentWithForm {
```

but I would actually like to get a **direct reference** to headerForm/contentForm which would save lot of hassle.

Comment: It's hard to answer without seeing the exact HTML structure, but assuming the children aren't PROJECTED components you might be checking in the wrong life cycle.  Are you checking for them in AfterViewInit?

Comment: Another option is to create a simple marker directive, add it to the child components and then query for that marker directive

Comment: I do not know how to "check for elements in AfterViewInit, what I tried was something like @ViewChildren('headerForm') componentsWithForms: QueryList<NgForm>; to the Parent component, but this results in undefined

Comment: But are you checking in the correct life cycle?  it was unclear from your code snippet.   You need to check in ngAfterViewInit

Comment: Ah, do you mean when do I check for the @ViewChildren value ? In a button-click-handler in the Parent component - long, long after everything is initialized

Comment: I don't know if this another approach meets your requirements (and sure don't resolve your question) but... why not create the forms in the "parent" and pass as `@Input` to  your components?

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's not a great change, but If each component with a form you have

```
 providers:[{provide:'FORM', useExisting:forwardRef(() => YourComponent)}]
```

and

```
 @ViewChild(NgForm) form
```

A directive like

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[haveform]'
})
export class HaveFormDirective implements AfterViewInit {
 form:NgForm
 constructor(@Host() @Inject('FORM') public component:any, ){  }
 ngAfterViewInit()
 {
  this.form=this.component.form
 }
}
```

Allow you write

```
<component haveform></component>
```

And you can reach the "form" like

```
 @ViewChildren(HaveFormDirective) forms:QueryList<HaveFormDirective>
 this.forms.forEach(x=>console.log(x.form.value)
```

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqtxyy?file=src%2Fhave-form.directive.ts,src%2Fform1.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: This is usually how I do it, using a marker directive.

Comment: This looks promising, but does it mean all components using this directive has name the form @ViewChild property the same ? ('form' in this case) ?

Answer (score 0):

It think you could use a better solution like `@Input()/@Output()` for parent <-> child component communication. But if u want to use `@ViewChild`, It will be best to start at official docs:

**https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#responding-to-view-changes**

```
export class AfterViewComponent implements  AfterViewChecked, AfterViewInit {
  private prevHero = '';

  // Query for a VIEW child of type `ChildViewComponent`
  @ViewChild(ChildViewComponent) viewChild!: ChildViewComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // viewChild is set after the view has been initialized
    this.logIt('AfterViewInit');
    this.doSomething();
  }

// ...
}
```

**EDITED:**

You can make a base class for all your components with form that contains `resetFormState() {}` method implementation:

```
@Directive()
export class YourFormDirective {
     resetFormState() {  //... }
}

export class HeaderComponent extends YourFormDirective {}

export class ContentComponent extends YourFormDirective {}
```

And then in parent, query for `WithFormDirective`:

```
@ViewChildren(WithFormDirective) componentsWithForms!: QueryList<WithFormDirective>;
```

So you can call it without type casting:

```
this.componentsWithForms.forEach(component => component.resetFormState());
```

Comment: Please look at the provided description, I already query for a component, what I want to is to query for a NgForm IN this component or for its Ref

Comment: I know this approach, I mentioned it in my original question. But it feels like lot of boilerplate compared to having direct references to the NgForms of the children.